# .net double to decimal conversion dilemma - looking for suggestions

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

All,

My setup:

- We are storing lat/lng as decimal values (up to 6 decimal places) in database which are mapped in the domain model (loaded entity) as decimal values (of lat/lng)
- In the application though we use a class "Location" that performs operations on lat/lng which are in double format (because the .net Math api works in doubles)

Therefore, when we load lat/lng from database in decimal, it ends used by the application as double(s). And that's the problem! 
Conversion of double -> dec (rounding occurs) and I know why it happens so what's the best work around this?

Example of the problem:

The rounding is a problem in cases where a user entered a lat in component form (DMS) and after the conversion and saving the lat into database a different value is saved. When it is loaded back and viewed by the user in component form, it is not what he entered initially.

Ex:

User entered: N10-01-03.5

When loaded back: N10-01-03.468 (caused by dbl -> dec conversion)

Possible solutions:

1) Use decimals (for lat/lng) in my "Location" class and every time I do a calculation, I would convert lat/lng from dec -> dbl and then back to dec.

2) Store lat/lng as doubles in the database (not sure if this will be a problem in the future). We want accuracy to 6 decimal places.

3) Your suggestion .....

Comment: double precision numbers should not have rounding errors for only 6 decimal places.  How large are the numbers to the left of the decimal point?

Comment: First off, I agree with JohnCarpenter.  that discrepancy looks much larger than what I would expect from mere rounding errors between decimal and double

Comment: Secondly, If you really need your values to be that precise, then you probably want to be using decimal everywhere.

Comment: See my answer, thx guys for your comments.

Comment: "Secondly, If you really need your values to be that precise, then you probably want to be using decimal everywhere". Yes, but then every time I need to do some trig calculations in .net using Math.cos(), etc, i have to convert values to double, and then back to decimal. That's not great either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, I found the problem. Although, there's some rounding going on between dbl -> dec the reason why 3.5 sec became 3.468 is the fact that in my hibernate mapping I did not set precision/scale values, so hibernate used defaults and truncated the value to 5th decimal place, regardless of my prec/scale set in the database.

So the value '10.0176388888889' was saved as '10.0176300000000000'.